# third party jars in map reduce job

Tags: hadoop, jar, mapreduce, oozie

I have situation where my map reduce job is dependent on third party libraries like hive-hcatalog-xxx.jar. I am running all my jobs through oozie. Mapreduce jobs are run via java action. What is the best way to include third party libraries in my job? I have two options in hand

1. Bundle all the dependent jars into the main jar and create a fat jar.
2. Keep all the dependent jars in an HDFS location and add it via -libjars option

Which one I can choose? Please advice.

As my mapreduce job is invoked through a java action of oozie, the libraries available in oozie lib folder is not added to the classpath of mapper/reducer. If I change this java action to map reduce action, will the jars be available?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

> 1.Bundle all the dependent jars into the main jar and create a fat jar.
>                                  OR 
>   2.Keep all the dependent jars in an HDFS location and add it via
>   -libjars option Which one I can choose?

Although, both approaches are in practice.  I'd suggest Uber jar
 i.e your first approach.

Uber jar : A jar that has a `lib/` folder inside which carries more dependent jars (a structure known as 'uber' jars), and you submit the job via a regular 'hadoop jar' command, these lib/.jars get picked up by the framework because the supplied jar is specified explicitly via `conf.setJarByClass` or `conf.setJar`. That is, if this user uber jar goes to the JT as the mapred...jar, then it is handled by the framework properly and the lib/.jars are all considered and placed on the `classpath`.

> Why

The advantage is that you can distribute your uber-jar and not care at all whether or not dependencies are installed at the destination, as your uber-jar actually has no dependencies.

> As my mapreduce job is invoked through a java action of oozie, the
>   libraries available in oozie lib folder is not added to the classpath
>   of mapper/reducer. If I change this java action to map reduce action,
>   will the jars be available?

For the above question, since answer is broad,

I have `sharelib` links from [CDH4.xx](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/12/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie/) , [CDH5.xx](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2014/05/how-to-use-the-sharelib-in-apache-oozie-cdh-5/) & 
[How to configure Mapreduce action with Oozie shre lib.](http://www.tanzirmusabbir.com/2013/03/oozie-example-java-action-mapreduce-jobs.html) for you

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Uber jar would be bigger in size and does it affect job startup time?

Comment: through bit difference is there since its single jar; spark related development also, most of the people using uber jar

Answer (score 1):

You can obviously adopt the approaches suggested by you, But Oozie has sharelib prepared for `hcatalog`. You can use them out of the box with `oozie.action.sharelib.for.actiontype` property in your `job.properties`. For the `java` action you can specify:

```
oozie.action.sharelib.for.java=hcatalog
```

This will load the libraries from the oozie share lib `hcatalog` into your launcher job. This should do the job.

You can checkout the content of the `hcatalog` here:

```
 hdfs dfs -ls /user/oozie/share/lib/lib_*/hcatalog
```